# I want to display record getting value from database where id=id (insert value into database from getter method not work) in java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I create A java file Name Attend.java

```
public class Attend {
String attend_id,studname,owner;

public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;

}public String getStudname() {
    return Studname;
}

public void setStudname(String Studname) {
    this.Studname = Studname;
}

public String getAttend_id() {
    return attend_id;
}

public void setAttend_id(String attend_id) {
    this.attend_id = attend_id;
}} ;
```

other file DAO file AttendDao.java

```
, public class AttendDao {public static List<Attend> getAllRecords(){
    List<Attend> list=new ArrayList<Attend>();
        //Attend u1=null; 
    try{
        Connection con=DbConnector.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select attend_id,studname,owner from attend_detail where owner=?");
        Attend u1 = null;
        //System.out.println(u1.getOwner());
        ps.setString(1,u1.getOwner());
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Attend u=new Attend();
            u.setAttend_id(rs.getString("attend_id"));
            u.setStudname(rs.getString("studname"));
            u.setOwner(rs.getString("owner"));
            list.add(u);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e1){System.out.println("sql error:"+e1);
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    return list;
    //}
}},
```

i want to get this owner value from database if owner="xyz@xyz.com" then it will display only that rows data

This is my database and its value.. database name Attend_detail.

```
attend_id  studname     owner 
ATN001     abcd       xyz@xyz.com
ATN002     efgh       null
```

this my jsp view.jsp

```
<body>
<%@page import="com.attend.detail.AttendDao,com.attend.detail.Attend,java.util.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<div class="container">

<h1>Attendance List</h1>

<%
 List<Attend> list=AttendDao.getAllRecords();
 request.setAttribute("list",list);
 %>

 <div class="table-responsive" width="100%">
 <table id="myTable" class="display table table-bordered" width="99%" >
 <thead>  
      <tr>  
        <th>Attend_id</th>  
        <th>Student_id</th>   
        <th>owner</th>
      </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="u">  
      <tr>  
        <td>${u.getAttend_id()}</td>  
        <td>${u.getStudentid()}</td> 
        <td>${u.getOwner()}</td>  
      </tr> 
      </c:forEach> 
    </tbody>  

    </table>
    </div></body>
```

it shows NullpointerException 
how to solve it.. please rply.

Comment: its not duplicate sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign some value after `Attend u1 = null`, which is initialize with `null`.

```
    Attend u1 = null; 
    //System.out.println(u1.getOwner());
    ps.setString(1,u1.getOwner());
```

So, basically, `u1` has `null` and you need to assign `Attend` object to correct this issue.

Comment: How can I tell what you need to assign ? Probably, you need to get the value from the list

Comment: @BURHANUDDIN check my updated answer.

Comment: @BURHANUDDIN you need to assign `new Attend()` memory location to be able to use the `ul` methods and data fields.

Comment: @abcOfJavaAndCPP that will solve the issue, but that isn't a solution.

Comment: i used  Attend u1 = new Attend(); 
           //System.out.println(u1.getOwner());
            ps.setString(1,u1.getOwner());    but i will show null

Comment: @BURHANUDDIN That's obvious. As I mentioned. creating an object of `Attend` solve null pointer exception. But, that won't be solution. When you create instance of `Attend` all the member variable will be initialize with default value. And `getOwner()` will return `null`

Comment: @BURHANUDDIN how can you expect any value before setting it ? Where are you setting this value ??? you haven't shown that part of the code

Comment: @Ravi got the solution.

Comment: @Ravi thanks..........

Comment: @BURHANUDDIN you need to accept the answer.